# SQL Server : subtract last row from first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, difference

I have a query that returns a lot of rows. I would need the difference between the values in the last row and the first row. `TimeCol` is a `DateTime` column, all other columns are of type `float`.

My current (simplified) query is this:

```
select 
    timeCol, TotSoap_W1, TotSoap_W2, TotEnergy
from
    TotEnergy
where 
    TimeCol >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00' and timeCol < '2019-03-02 00:00:00'
order by 
    TimeCol asc
```

Comment: Do you mean between first and last TimeCol value?

Comment: i get all the rows that fall in this time range. i would need the difference in soap consumption for example.. so the TotSoap_W1 from the last row, minus the TotSoap_W1 from the first row..

Comment: First and last according to what criteria? Rows have no order unless one is imposed by an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Table structure, sample data, and the expected outcome would be helpful.

Comment: added order by.. sorry

Comment: What do you want to return apart from the difference? You an use the `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` analytic functions to return the difference in every row for example, along with each `timecol` and `totenergy`. Or you could use `DISTINCT` and return only the difference

Comment: all i need is the difference between the last and the first row of the float columns.. date is only used to filter. there are 50 or so float columns, and i would simply need the difference between the last row and the first row of each column.

Comment: @sharkyenergy you can use `TOP 1 LAST_VALUE()... - FIRST_VALUE()....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best way of doing but should do the job:

```
SELECT B.TotSoap_W1-A.TotSoap_W1 as TotSoap_W1, B.TotSoap_W2-A.TotSoap_W2 as TotSoap_W2, B.TotEnergy-A.TotEnergy as TotEnergy
FROM
(select TOP(1) timeCol, TotSoap_W1, TotSoap_W2, TotEnergy
from TotEnergy
where TimeCol >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00' and timeCol < '2019-03-02 00:00:00'
order by TimeCol ASC) A,
(select TOP(1) timeCol, TotSoap_W1, TotSoap_W2, TotEnergy
from TotEnergy
where TimeCol >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00' and timeCol < '2019-03-02 00:00:00'
order by TimeCol DESC
) B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FIRST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [LAST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) analytic functions :

```
select top 1 LAST_VALUE(TotSoap_W1) OVER (ORDER BY TimeCol ROWS
                                          BETWEEN UNBOUNDEDPRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
             - FIRST_VALUE(TotSoap_W1)
from TotEnergy
where TimeCol >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00' and timeCol < '2019-03-02 00:00:00'
order by TimeCol asc
```

`LAST_VALUE` returnes the last value in each group/result set according to the sorting order. In this query, it would be the same as returning each row's `TotSoap_W1` value. To make it return the last value in all the results, we need to add the `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDEDPRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` clause